# solve the inequality $\frac{1}{x}<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My trial :

For $x>0$, $\frac{1}{x}<1\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{x}x<1x\Longrightarrow 1<x$

For $x<0$, $\frac{1}{x}<1\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{x}x>1x\Longrightarrow 1>x$

Hence :$x<1\vee x>1$

Comment: $x<0\vee x>1$. Don't forget that you obtained $1>x$ under the assumption $x<0$.

Comment: So my proof is wrong??

Comment: The last step is incorrect. The first line is correct. The second is correct too, but when you get to $1>x$ remember you were assuming $x<0$. So, $1>x$ same as $x<1$ is the interval $(-\infty,1)$ and $x<0$ is the interval $(-\infty,0)$, their intersection, i.e. when $x<0$ and $1>x$ hold simultaneously is $(-\infty,0)$. In this case, since $x<0$ is a stronger restriction than $1>x$, the $1>x$ becomes redundant, but you need to keep the $x<0$ that you started with. @JMoravitz I do not follow your comment.

Comment: @Mirko you are correct.  I misread the center.  That being said, perhaps you could convert that into an answer to remove this from the unanswered queue.  That was a fine explanation.

Comment: Let us see.We have :$x>0\Longrightarrow 1<x$,also $x<0\Longrightarrow x<1$..Hence by the law of logic called proof by cases we have: $x>0\vee x<0\Longrightarrow x>1\vee x<1$........(1).But since $\neg(x=0)$  ,and using the law of trichotomy we have:$x>0\vee x<0$ ......(2).Thus from (1) and (2) and using the law of logic called M.Ponens we have: $x>1\vee x<1$ . Where is the mistake??

Comment: @chris Could you please provide more details or a reference to what you call proof by cases, how you use it, and how it entails the implication you claim it does? Also, are you answering the OP question, or posting another question instead?

Comment: Any book of logic you refer to you will find the proof by cases law of propositional  calculus or .Another name for that law is constractive dillema.The general form of that law is : From the wff of the form : $A\vee B$,$A\Longrightarrow C$,$B\Longrightarrow D$ we can infer $C\vee D$ .iN OUR CASE .Put $A=x>0$,$B=x<0$,$C=x>1$,$D=x<1$ ,then by using the above law you will get :$x>1\vee x<1$.I am defending the OP proof

Comment: Perhaps you should consider $(A\land (A\to C))\lor(B\land (B\to D))$. This reduces to $(A\land C)\lor(B\land D)$. As it happens for the above example, $A\land C \iff C$, and $B\land D \iff B$, so we end up with $C\lor B$. This is what I mean when I say don't forget that $x<0$. We should not only be looking at $x<0\to x<1$ but at $(x<0)\land((x<0)\to(x<1))$ which reduces to $x<0$. Hope this helps, as it is closest to what I could get, to understand how you were arguing, using logic rules.

Comment: $(A\wedge (A\Longrightarrow C))\vee (B\vee (B\Longrightarrow D$

Comment: $A\wedge(A\Longrightarrow C))\vee(B\wedge(B\Longrightarrow D))$ IT reduces to $C\vee D)$

Comment: only if $D$ is stronger than $B$, which is not the case for the problem under consideration. Note that if $T$ denotes truth, then $B\to T$ for all $B$, but $B\land(B\to T)$ reduced to $B\land T$ which reduced to $B$, not to $T$. Similarly, if $D$ is weaker than $B$ then $B\to D$ reduces to $T$, and $B\land(B\to D)$ reduced to $B$. (You may delete any comments that you posted by inadvertently hitting the enter key, cutting them in the middle before they were posted. Move the mouse over your comment, then a circled x should appear, click on it to delete incomplete or mistyped comments).

Comment: What is the DEFINITION OF A STRONG OR A WEAK well formed formula  (wff) in logic??

Comment: Your question is about algebra-precalculus, and as such has been answered (correctly, by two different people). If you are interested in logic and wff, you need to post another question. In my answer I mean that $B=x<0$ is a stronger condition than $D=x<1$ since $B$ is more restrictive. Fewer $x$'s satisfy $B$, more $x$'s satisfy $D$, so $B$ is stronger in the sense that it has more power to restrict the possible values of $x$ in the answer. It is not only about the formula (as a form, syntax) but also about its meaning, semantics.

Comment: you have to use correct and well founded mathematical and logical means to convince me..also when asked you have to unswer directly .you cannot separate maths from logic,they go hand in hand in every mathematical proof

Answer (score 1):

The last step is incorrect. The first line is correct. The second is correct too, but when you get to $1>x$ remember you were assuming $x<0$. So, $1>x$ same as $x<1$ is the interval $(−\infty,1)$ and $x<0$ is the interval $(−\infty,0)$, their intersection, i.e. when $x<0$ and $1>x$ hold simultaneously is $(−∞,0)$. In this case, since $x<0$ is a stronger restriction than $1>x$, the $1>x$ becomes redundant, but you need to keep the $x<0$ that you started with.

So the second line results in $x<0$.

In the first line you are assuming $x>0$ and then obtaining $x>1$. This time $x>1$ is the stronger condition, and $x>0$ happens to be redundant. So from the first line you get $x>1$ as a valid solution.

Thus the answer would be $x<0\vee x>1$.

In general (not directly related to this problem) when two inequalities hold together simultaneously, then you should intersect the respective intervals. 
For example, $x>6$ and $11>x$ are satisfied simultaneously by those $x$ that are in $(6,\infty)\cap(-\infty,11)=(6,11)$ also written as $6<x<11$.

Edit prompted by the comments.
Put $A=x>0$, $B=x<0$, $C=x>1$, $D=x<1$. Then consider cases as follows:
$(A∧(A→C))∨(B∧(B→D))$. This reduces to $(A∧C)∨(B∧D)$.
As it happens for the above example, $A∧C⟺C$, and $B∧D⟺B$, so we end up with $C∨B$, that is $x>1 \lor x<0$. This is what I mean when I say don't forget that $x<0$. We should not only be looking at $x<0→x<1$ but at $(x<0)∧((x<0)→(x<1))$ which reduces to $x<0$.

Comment: According to which law of logic ,when,$ A $ implies $ B$ ,then $A$ and $B$ hold together.Because that is what you claim in the case where: $x<0\Longrightarrow x<1$

Comment: If $A\to B$ and $A\to C$ then $A\to B\land C$. Use when $C=A$ with $A$ being $x<0$, and $B$ being $x<1$. Without using logic, but quite convincing, sketch the graph of $y=\dfrac 1x$ and see for which $x$ it is below the graph of the horizontal line $y=1$.

Comment: So if $A\Longrightarrow B$ and $A\Longrightarrow A$ ,then $A\

Comment: So if $A\Longrightarrow B$ and $A\Longrightarrow A$ ,then $A\Longrightarrow A\wedge B$.How do you prove $A\Longrightarrow A$? Also In my proof there is not a line having the implication $A\Longrightarrow A$.You suggesting an entirely different proof

Comment: You previous comments seems unfinished, ending \$A\ . Without rules of logic which I find confusing to follow formally, think that on the first line you start with $x>0$ and building on top of that you get $x>1$, which is a more restrictive, and more specific condition, so it takes over. On the second line, start with $x<0$ obtain $x<1$ but $x<1$ brings nothing new, since $x<1$ is a weaker condition than $x<0$. So you may throw the $x<1$ away, provided you keep the $x<0$, since the $x<1$ is trivially satisfied if $x<0$. $A\to A$ is a tautology. Only correcting a detail in your proof.

Comment: In propositional calculus every theorem is a tautology ,hence provable.You are not correcting my proof, because my proof is correct .YOU are adding  without any incentive the fact $x<0\Longrightarrow x<0$,to get $x<0\Longrightarrow x<0\wedge x<1$ hence you are suggesting a different proof

Comment: please see my last comment that I posted under your question. Perhaps the way you start was not quite complete. If your proof is incorrect then it will have to be replaced by a correct one, which by necessity will be different. You proof is not correct as posted.

Answer (score 0):

You've done nearly everything correctly and in a nice careful way. However, be careful when you combine them. Your first line proves:

> If $x>0$ then $\frac{1}x<1$ if and only if $1<x$.

Your second line proves

> If $x<0$ then $\frac{1}x<1$ if and only if $x<1$.

The proper way to combine these is into the statement:

> $\frac{1}x<1$ if and only if either:
>
> - $x>0$ and $1<x$
> - $x<0$ and $x<1$

where we incorporate the conditions on either of our results into our lines. In particular, we may simplify this to

> $\frac{1}x < 1$ if and only if either $1<x$ or $x<0$.

Which is different from what you got, since you forgot to combine the condition $x<0$ into the second line's result.

Comment: i do not follow

Comment: @chris Where does this post lose you? Do you see, for instance, why when we have $x=\frac{1}2$ we have to apply the logic of your first line rather than the second one (since, in this case, multiplying by $x$ does not reverse the order)?

Comment: correct.So my proof although correct does not solve the problem.Thus this type of approach ,using different values for $x$  does not solve the problem ,Do you agree??

Comment: @chris The approach you start on is reasonable and really the only way to do this - the error is entirely in how you combine things. Consider a machine that takes in $x$ and tells you whether $\frac{1}x<1$. First, it checks whether $x$ is positive: if it is, then we can legally check $1<x$ instead. If it sees that $x$ is negative, then it gets to $x<1$ instead - which is true of all negative numbers. We can say that the machine says "yes" whenever $x$ is negative. Similarly, we can say that the machine says "yes" whenever $1<x$ since if $1<x$ then $x$ is positive and goes through that machine.